# I want my network connections immutable, instead of getting "System policy prevents control of network connections" dialog

Tags: networking, network-manager, xrdp, dialog

I have a Kubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS server.
Every time anyone remotely logs in with via xrdp, they are always shown a dialog
`System policy prevents control of network connections`
and they are asked to authenticate. This dialog appears automatically immediately after login.

However, nobody should change any of they network connections on this server. The interfaces are ethernet, and at this stage of the server's life, the connections should be immutable. The dialog is an annoyance at best, and possibly a source of user-initiated system failure. I would greatly prefer the NetworkManager app to be disabled.

How should I do this on Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean to say if the users try to fiddle with the Network Manager App then they see this dialog, or this dialog pops up spontaneously? Please edit the question and add the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The popup you are seeing (only in your remote session) is probably due to the polkit technology that basically control what a user can (and cant do) based on the session the user is logged on....

Since you are using Kubuntu and thus KDE Desktop interface, you will need to create a additional file under /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/ that will basically create an polkit exception and you will not see the popup anymore.

From your terminal session, type the following piece of code.... (you need sudo right to create the file under /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/) so you will be prompted for a password.....

```
sudo bash -c "cat >/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/47-allow-networkd.pkla" <<EOF
[Allow Network Control all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
EOF
```

When the file is created, try to perform an xrdp connection and the popup message should be gone....

Hope this help

More information about similar issue can be found at

1. [xRDP – The Infamous “Authentication Required to Create Managed Color
   Device” Explained](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12073)
2. [xRDP – How to Fix the Infamous system crash popups in Ubuntu 18.04 (and previous versions)](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043)

Comment: Belated thanks!

Comment: Hmm, but what if one just wants the popup not to appear? Dismissing it doesn't cause any issues, and in my case I certainly don't want to give the user in question such permissions anyways.

Comment: thanks! this solution helped us to solve a situation where Electron-based application was not working properly when requesting a file from Ubuntu-based system via custom protocol

Answer (score 0):

On our ubuntu server removing the package plasma-nm was sufficient to remove the popup.. *without* granting users access to network settings

```
apt remove plasma-nm
```